# If tIf the product of two symmetric matrices is diagonal, must the two matrices be diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

We all know that a real symmetric matrix can be diagonalized，but in this situation must it be one itself?

Comment: The title and the body of the Question almost seem to be asking different things, although the body does not make sense by itself.   Please edit to give a self-contained presentation in the body.

Answer (score 5):

No. Take your favourite (or second favourite) symmetric nondiagonal invertible Matrix $A$. Then its inverse $A^{-1}$ has the same properties and $A A^{-1} = I$ is diagonal.